# Custom UIView in Cocos2d-iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making an iOS game using Cocos2d and need to customize the look of a UITableView. It seems that  [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) provides a good framework to start with, and the sample code works well when I test it by itself. The problem is that I can't get it to work in my cocos2d app.

The sample uses this code to create the custom UIViewController: (window is a UIWindow and viewController is the EasyCustomTableController)

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but when I use that code, the EasyCustomTableController's viewDidLoad function never runs, and nothing happens within my game. I can get the viewDidLoad function to run by using this code:

```
levelMenu = [[EasyCustomTableController alloc] init];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:levelMenu.view];
```

but again, nothing happens in my game and the view never comes up.

How can I get the custom UIViewController to work in my cocos2d app?

EDIT:

I can get a UIView with a white background to show, so there must be a problem with levelMenu.view:

```
UIApplication* clientApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIWindow* topWindow = [clientApp keyWindow];
if (!topWindow) {
    topWindow = [[clientApp windows] objectAtIndex:0];
} 
//Works
UIView *white = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
white.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:255];
[topWindow addSubview:white];

//Doesn't work
levelMenu = [[EasyCustomTableController alloc] init];
[topWindow addSubview:levelMenu.view];
```

I haven't changed levelMenu's class code from the sample - you can see viewDidLoad in the first code box [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIApplication* clientApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];   
UIWindow* topWindow = [clientApp keyWindow];
if (!topWindow) {
    topWindow = [[clientApp windows] objectAtIndex:0];
}
[topWindow addSubview:levelMenu.view];
```

If you don't see anything, then there is maybe a problem with the levelMenu.view. Try with a simple basic UIView with white background to test this.

Comment: A white UIView comes up, but levelMenu.view doesn't. I haven't changed that code at all from the sample http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: HAve you tried to toglgle this off "The code includes a #define at the top that allows you to toggle the custom drawing on and off." ?

Comment: Turning it off makes no difference. My input locks up but the view doesn't come up

Comment: Well, I have no idea, the problem seems to be on the EasyCustomTableController implementation. Maybe you should try to display this view on a classic UIKit app first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview addSubview:levelMenu.view];
```

Comment: viewDidLoad runs and my game stops processing input, but the table view still doesn't come up.

Comment: try `bringSubviewToFront:` in your `viewDidLoad`. also make sure `view.frame` is correct

Comment: The new code in my edit should bring the view to the front. I tried setting levelMenu.tableView.frame to fit the screen but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

first you make CCLayer and make Pushscreen which we make in cocos2d.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[ScoreLayer node]];
```

in this layer ScoreLayer.h

```
    @interface ScoreLayer : CCLayer <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
        AppController *myApp;
        UIView *view;
        UITableView *tblView;
 UIToolbar *toolbar;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
    NSMutableArray *ScoreArray;

    }
    @property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tblView;
```

ScoreLayer.m

```
-(id) init
{
    myApp = (AppController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self = [super init];
    // create view
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    // create Table
    tblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 436)];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    tblView.dataSource = self;
   // tblView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
    //table.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;

    ScoreArray = [myApp getScoreList];
    [view addSubview:tblView];
toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44)];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    //Create a button
    backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Return to the main menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backClicked:)];

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton,nil] animated:YES];
    [view addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];

    // add the view to the director
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:view];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: What is AppController? I commented out those lines and got a 'NSInvalidArgumentException' at -[ScoreLayer tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]

Comment: oye its my delegate object you just remove it and also from .h file declaration of that AppController *myApp;

Comment: put table view dalegate mathods in class..it call but you dont put in .m file

Comment: which class are you referring to?

Comment: in ScoreLayer.m put table view delegate method.

Comment: Did that, but I'm still getting the same error with numberOfRowsInSection